# best way to change value of an object from an array of objects when given a key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working (learning) in React. I have an array of objects which hold info on gamertags. They are rated with up to five stars and this function is called when a user clicks on the stars in the GUI to alter the rating.

my solution:
I make a copy of state, iterate over the copy, check each entry for the key, reassign the number of stars, then use my setState hook to assign the altered array.

Is there a more concise way to do this? I searched all over stack and google and couldn't find anything. I feel like I should be able to map, use an arrow function and or a ternary. Thanks for any comments on styles, JS and ES6 seems to be all about that. Thx fam.

```
  function changeStars(stars, key) {
    console.log(stars, key);
    const newRatingInventory = [ ...tagInventory];

    for (const [index] of newRatingInventory.entries()) {
      if (newRatingInventory[index].timeStamp === key) {
        newRatingInventory[index].stars = stars;
      }
    }
    setTagInventory([...newRatingInventory]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the spread syntax doesn't creates a deep copy - it just creates a new array but the objects are not cloned. So any changes made to any object inside the new array will mutate the original object.

Currently you are mutating the state directly which is not the correct way to update the state in React.

You should use the `.map()` method to iterate over the array, create and return a new object if the condition `newRatingInventory[index].timeStamp === key` evaluates to true.

```
function changeStars(stars, key) {
    const newState = tagInventory.map(obj => {
       if (obj.timeStamp === key) { 
          // return a new object with the updated 
          // value of "stars" property.
          return { ...obj, stars };
       }
       
       // if the above condition is not true,
       // return the current object as it is.
       return obj;
    });
   
    // update the state
    setTagInventory(newState);
}
```

Comment: works like a champ. thx, i didn't realize it wasn't a deep copy, i googled it and learned that the spread operator only goes 1 level deep on an array, so like you said, the objects themselves are shallow and not clones. glad i asked, this is super helpful to know. thx, i appreciate you

Answer (score 0):

There is a multipal way to do this

my recommendation one is map.

```
const changeStars = (stars, key) => {
let tempRating = tagInventory && tagInventory.length > 0 && 
    tagInventory.map(item => item.timeStamp === key ? {...item, stars} : item);
 setTagInventory(tempRating)
}
```